# Time.sleep in lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, sleep

I was wondering how I can modify the following code to insert a time.sleep(0.5), since the GoogleTranslator API crashes if you send more than 5 request wihtin a second.

```
test["Label"]=test["cleanText"].apply(lambda x:GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(x))
```

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the `Label` and `cleanText` contains, but can't you can move the lambda out, create a separate function that has the `time.sleep` and `GoogleTranslator` logic, then use that inside `apply`?